# Overriding existing react.js class

Tags: javascript, components, carousel, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using http://react-bootstrap.github.io/ Carousel component. Inside, there is a CarouselItem component, so it look like this:

```
        return (
          <Carousel>
            <CarouselItem key={obj.src1}>
              <EmbeddedVideo provider={obj.provider1} videoId={obj.src1} />
            </CarouselItem>
            <CarouselItem key={obj.src2}>
              <EmbeddedVideo provider={obj.provider2} videoId={obj.src2} />
            </CarouselItem>
            ...
          </Carousel>
        );
```

Everything works fine, but how to get CarouselItem props? I would like to listen inside EmbeddedVideo for props change of CarouselItem.props.active to determine whether it's visible, and if not, pause video inside EmbeddedVideo component.

I belive I could just create EmbeddedVideo insidie CarouselItem render method and there pass it's active prop, but I don't want to copy-paste whole CarouselItem to add just one element.

So how can I modify it? Or there is some other way to controll EmbeddedVideo with CarouselItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you write that return statement that you pasted has total control over the props of `CarouselItem`. It looks like you are not setting any props on `CarouselItem`.

If you are talking about the state of `CarouselItem`, you will need to pass a callback function to `CarouselItem` as a prop that will get called when its state changes so that the parent component can respond appropriately.